# How to assign value to attributes for a string for classification?

Tags: java, dataset, classification, weka, phishing

I am trying to implement a system that can detect phishing websites. The input will consist of the website URL, taken through a web page. I am using the UCI Phishing Data set (which has around 30 attributes) and I am training and testing the J48 Classification Model to predict future instances.

**Attributes**

```
@relation phishing
@attribute having_IP_Address  { -1,1 }
@attribute URL_Length   { 1,0,-1 }
@attribute Shortining_Service { 1,-1 }
@attribute having_At_Symbol   { 1,-1 }
@attribute double_slash_redirecting { -1,1 }
@attribute Prefix_Suffix  { -1,1 }
@attribute having_Sub_Domain  { -1,0,1 }
@attribute SSLfinal_State  { -1,1,0 }
@attribute Domain_registeration_length { -1,1 }
@attribute Favicon { 1,-1 }
@attribute port { 1,-1 }
@attribute HTTPS_token { -1,1 }
@attribute Request_URL  { 1,-1 }
@attribute URL_of_Anchor { -1,0,1 }
@attribute Links_in_tags { 1,-1,0 }
@attribute SFH  { -1,1,0 }
@attribute Submitting_to_email { -1,1 }
@attribute Abnormal_URL { -1,1 }
@attribute Redirect  { 0,1 }
@attribute on_mouseover  { 1,-1 }
@attribute RightClick  { 1,-1 }
@attribute popUpWidnow  { 1,-1 }
@attribute Iframe { 1,-1 }
@attribute age_of_domain  { -1,1 }
@attribute DNSRecord   { -1,1 }
@attribute web_traffic  { -1,0,1 }
@attribute Page_Rank { -1,1 }
@attribute Google_Index { 1,-1 }
@attribute Links_pointing_to_page { 1,0,-1 }
@attribute Statistical_report { -1,1 }
@attribute Result  { -1,1 }
```

**Code**

```
package weka1;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Random;

import weka.classifiers.Evaluation;
import weka.classifiers.trees.J48;
import weka.core.Instances;
public class file1 {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
   {
     BufferedReader breader= null;
     breader=new BufferedReader( new        FileReader("C:\\Users\\.Gayatjhri\\Desktop\\phishing_training.arff"));

     Instances train1= new Instances(breader);
    train1.setClassIndex(30);
    breader=new BufferedReader( new FileReader("C:\\Users\\.Gayatjhri\\Desktop\\phishing_test.arff"));

    Instances test= new Instances(breader);
    test.setClassIndex(30);
      breader.close();

      J48 tree=new J48();
      tree.buildClassifier(train1);
      Instances labeled= new Instances(test);
    Evaluation eval= new Evaluation(train1);


      eval.crossValidateModel(tree, train1, 10, new Random(1));
    System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString("Results\n==========================================\n", true));
    System.out.println(eval.fMeasure(1)+ ""+ eval.precision(1)+ ""+ eval.recall(1));

      for(int i=0; i<test.numInstances(); i++){
      double clsLabel= tree.classifyInstance(test.instance(i));
      labeled.instance(i).setClassValue(clsLabel); 
      }

  BufferedWriter writer=new BufferedWriter(
          new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\.Gayatjhri\\Desktop\\phishing_labeledd.arff"));
          writer.write(labeled.toString());
          writer.close(); 
}
```

}

**How can I assign values to these 30 attributes for any given URL ?**

Comment: Sorry, you are assuming we share your context. We have no idea what you are describing. You will have to describe the problem in detail and provide your existing code.  For example, in _"assign value to the attributes for any given URL"_ what do you mean by "value", and "attributes"?  Please [edit] your question with more details.

Comment: @JimGarrison I have revised the question